# What happens if flink's keyBy operator is given distinct key followed by tumbling window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My flink job has keyBy operator which takes date~clientId(date as yyyymmddhhMM, MM as minutes which changes after 5 mins) as key. This operator is followed by tumbling window of 5 mins. We have kafka input of 3 millions/min events on an average and around 20 millions/min events on peak time. Checkpointing duration and minimum pause between two checkpoiting is 3 mins.

Now here are my doubts :

1) Does the state created by keyBy is persisted forever or it's evicted after 5 minutes.

2) What changes are required in case i change this window to 30 minutes.

3) How the checkpointing time is affected by the window size.

4) What will be effect in a scenerio where number of distinct client in any 5 minutes goes 5-10 times. Will this create data skew. As 1-2 sub-tasks in my job always takes around 1-2 minutes as compare to other 800 sub-taks which completes in 10-15 seconds.

5) I am getting one exception once in every 5-6 hours which restarts the flink job. TimerException{java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException} at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SystemProcessingTimeService$TriggerTask. What maybe the probable reason.

Comment: Which state backend are you using?

Comment: I am using FsStateBackend

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

keyBy is not an operator, and has no state. keyBy is simply a declaration of how the stream is to be repartitioned. The tumbling window that follows the keyBy does have state, which is purged once the window is complete. You can see how much state each subtask has if you look at the breakdown in the checkpoint stats part of the web UI.

Here's an example:

[image: window subtask state sizes]

> What will be effect in a scenario where number of distinct client in any 5 minutes goes 5-10 times. Will this create data skew? As 1-2 sub-tasks in my job always takes around 1-2 minutes as compared to the other 800 sub-tasks which complete in 10-15 seconds.

Perhaps you have one or a few clients with many more events than the rest?

It would be interesting to understand why you are doing event-time-based keying followed by processing time windows, rather than using event time windows. (I assume you are using processing time windows, correct me if I'm wrong.)

Do you have any idea how many different timeframes are active at once? E.g., the window for 12:00-12:05 will receive many events with timestamps in the range of 12:00-12:05, plus some events for 11:55-12:00 that didn't arrive by 12:00. And possibly events for earlier timeframes, if that much delay is possible. It's hard to think about key skew without understanding what the active keyspace looks like.

Comment: I think checkpointing is triggered once all events which is consumed by the source (kafka) reaches to sink successfully. So checkpointing will not be triggered until all events in a tumbling window goes to sink. Since checkpointing is for recovery from failure, how does it make sense for tumbling window to make state and if it makes state then can you please tell me scenerio where it helps in failure recovery.

Comment: That's not how checkpointing works. https://training.ververica.com/snapshots.html is a good reference for understanding checkpointing in Flink. As a motivating example, consider having hour-long tumbling windows. Events collect in these windows for an hour, and are then processed. If the job fails near the end of the hour, and if the window contents weren't checkpointed, then that hour's worth of data would have to be re-ingested. But if you checkpoint that state every 10 seconds, then you have to, at most, rewind the sources by 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks David. Your example make sense. Initally i thought checkpoiting is triggered when checkpoit barrier reaches the sink but as you told i am wrong.  I am little confused between checkpoint barrier, snapshot and checkpointing. Can you tell me what's the relation between these three.

Comment: These terms are defined in the page from the Flink training site I linked to above.